# How to rotate column to row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rotation, row

How can I insert a column of table to row of another?

Example :

```
Value
------             
66
249
64
236
```

Rotate to this :

```
Digit1  Digit2  Digit3  Digit4
------------------------------
66      249     64      236
```

Answer (score 2):

here are several ways that you can transform data from multiple rows into columns. In SQL Server you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows to columns:

```
select Digit1,  Digit2,  Digit3,  Digit4
from
(
  select value
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for columnname in (Digit1,  Digit2,  Digit3,  Digit4)
) piv;
```

Comment: look at my query which written according to your recommend

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
DECLARE @tblRangeIP TABLE(Digit1 INT,Digit2 INT,Digit3 INT,Digit4 INT)

SELECT * FROM dbo.f_Eng_Str_SplitOneDim('66.249.64.236','.')

select Digit1,  Digit2,  Digit3,  Digit4
from 
(
  SELECT Value FROM dbo.f_Eng_Str_SplitOneDim('66.249.64.236','.')
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for d.Value in ( Digit1,  Digit2,  Digit3,  Digit4 )
) piv;
```